# How do I allow PopupWindows to wrap content over maximum preferred size?

Tags: android

I have an Android application that extensively uses PopupWindows. I've found that when the layouts of the contents of the PopupWindow use WRAP_CONTENT the dialog will only grow to a specific width before it begins truncating the content. I've traced this down to a config.xml dimension:

```
<dimen name="config_prefDialogWidth">580dp</dimen>
```

This dimension is used to create a maximum width in the measureHierarchy method of ViewRootImpl when determining the dialog size. The following code is used to access the value:

```
final DisplayMetrics packageMetrics = res.getDisplayMetrics();
res.getValue(com.android.internal.R.dimen.config_prefDialogWidth, mTmpValue, true);
int baseSize = 0;
if (mTmpValue.type == TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION) {
    baseSize = (int)mTmpValue.getDimension(packageMetrics);
}
```

The config_prefDialogWidth seems to have values for different device configurations, for example, the one I listed is for sw600dp. The one for default devices has 320dp as a value.

It would seem that this dimension is tuned for portrait orientation. Since my app forces landscape orientation this width is too small.

How do I override the config_prefDialogWidth dimension?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to make the width of your PopupWindow(wrap_content) larger than config_prefDialogWidth.

So here is my solution.

Choose one child View from the contentView of your PopupWindow.

A TextView, for example.

Override its `onMeasure`, add `View.MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL` if necessary:

```
        TextView textView = new TextView(context) {
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            // Text breaks into at least 2 lines, maybe the width is too small
            if (getLineCount() > 1) {
                int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
                final int desiredMaxWidth = (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels >> 2) * 3;
                // Compare with the desired max width you want, for example: 3/4 * screenWidth
                if (measuredWidth < disiredMaxWidth) {
                    // Tell ViewRootImpl that the width used to measure is too small
                    measuredWidth |= View.MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL;
                    // ViewRootImpl will remeasure contentView with screem width.
                    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, getMeasuredHeight());
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Generally speaking:

1. Override `onMeasure` of one child View
2. Check whether the measured width is too small
3. Ask for remeasurement if necessary (Using `View.MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL`)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override nor change `config_prefDialogWidth`'s value because this dimension is a internal resource. A workaround is you must create your own class. You can copy `PopupWindows` from its source code, and modify it.